# Jquery using find() with dynamic string

Tags: jquery

My question is how do I use the jquery find(), to find the correct listitems based on my checked checkboxes? I have tried building the string dynamicly but it does not work...?!

Is there an easier way?

I several listitems and a couple of checkboxes marked up like this.

```
 <li class="item" data-id="2" data-type="Bokföringsprogram" operativsystem='Windows' >
 <li class="item" data-id="2" data-type="Bokföringsprogram" operativsystem='Windows' operativsystem='MAC OS' >
 <li class="item" data-id="67" data-type="Faktureringsprogram" operativsystem='Windows'   operativsystem='MAC OS' >

<li><input type="checkbox" name="boxvalidator" value="Windows" />Windows<br /></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="boxvalidator" value="MAC OS" />MAC OS<br /></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="boxvalidator" value="Ubuntu" />Ubuntu<br /></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="boxvalidator" value="Linux" />Linux<br /></li>
```

Jquery code

```
$('input:checkbox[name="boxvalidator"]:checked').each(function() 
{ 
$boxchecked = $boxchecked + ",li[operativsystem=~" + $(this).attr('value') +  "],";
});

var $filteredPortfolio = $portfolioClone.find($boxchecked);
```

String looks like this:
undefined,li[operativsystem=~Windows],,li[operativsystem=~MAC OS],

must be an easier way of doing this?

Cheers & thanks for reading all the way down here!

Comment: What is `$portfolioClone`? What are you doing with the checkboxes? Your selector `$('input:checkbox[name="boxvalidator"]:checked')` looks correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this:

> String looks like this: undefined,li[operativsystem=~Windows],,li[operativsystem=~MAC OS],

it looks like you probably want to set `$boxchecked = ''` at some point outside that function.  Alternatively, you could do something like the following to avoid the extra commas:

```
$('input:checkbox[name="boxvalidator"]:checked').each(function() 
{
    if (typeof $boxchecked !== 'undefined') {
        $boxchecked = $boxchecked + ",";
    }
    else {
        $boxchecked = "";
    }
    $boxchecked = $boxchecked + "li[operativsystem=~" + $(this).attr('value') +  "]";
});
```

That being said, @veblock's solution looks like a better way of getting what you want.

Answer (score 0):

As sgarrett said your selector $('input:checkbox[name="boxvalidator"]:checked') looks ok. As you want to select list items not the checkboxes, just modify this selector to select the parent of the returned checkboxes:

$('input:checkbox[name="boxvalidator"]:checked').parent()